# Bootstrap Dropdown is clipped inside Panel

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, z-index

A .dropdown inside a table inside a .responsive-table inside a .panel and as you can see in the demo, the .dropdown gets clipped inside the .panel

Some sort of z-index or overflow bug inside Bootstrap I guess, how to fix it so that the dropdown shows up outside the panel when clicked?

DEMO: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJyave

CODE:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
        <h3 class="panel-title pull-left">Panel</h3>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>John Smith</td>
                    <td>32</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-block dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                            San Francisco
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                                <li><a href="#">San Francisco</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Los Angeles</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">New York</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dallas</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Seattle</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Miami</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add Person</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add following css

```
.table-responsive {
  overflow-x: visible !important;
  overflow-y: visible !important;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbVwVa)

Comment: Mmm nope, that kills the responsiveness of .table-responsive

Answer (score 2):

Just add

```
 .bs-example .dropdown{position:fixed}
```

to your CSS

Comment: that wont do if the dropdown is somewhere deep in the DOM, it always gets clipped

Answer (score 0):

`.dropdown {position:absolute;}` will make the dropdown show outside the `<td>` (on top of it)

https://jsfiddle.net/nowhqbm1/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13392774)

Comment: If the <div> inside the <td> is set to position:absolute; the dropdown will appear on top of the <table> (outside the panel) instead of inside the table cell. The class .dropdown refers to the code in the OP and also the codepen. I can't see how this solution is braking responsiveness either. Is it not up to the the guy asking for help to decide wether my suggestion is helpful or not?